# Help structuring a query with multiple many-to-many relationships

Tags: mysql, join, query, many-to-many

Assume that there are 4 tables, with association tables "between" each of them:

1. Machines
2. Products
3. Option Groups
4. Options

Machines may serve many products, and a product may "belong to" many machines. Products have many Option Groups and an option group can belong to multiple products. The same relationship exists between Option Groups and Options.

Ideally, I'd like to return all of the data for a "menu" (there is not a menus table - that's just how I'm referring to a group of products that belong to a machine) in a single call, but I'm struggling to get things working right.

Any help, including a simple nudge in the right direction, would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Sounds like you need a string of `JOINs` that connect the 4 Entity tables via the 3 Relationship (mapping) tables.